# How to install percona-xtrabackup on centos 6.3?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have installed mysql 5.5,and downloaded percona-xtrabackup-2.2.5-5027.el6.x86_64.rpm, then I use "rpm -ivh percona-xtrabackup-2.2.5-5027.el6.x86_64.rpm" to install xtrabackup, it tell me like that:

> Transaction Check Error:
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>     file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.5.39-2.el6.x86_64
>
> ### Error Summary

I want to use MySQL 5.5, not 5.1, what could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, uninstall mysql-libs-5.1
2nd, install MySQL-shared-compat
3rd, install xtrabackup
4th, install MySQL-server
P.S. MySQL-shared-compat and MySQL-server should be in same version.